# React - add editable tooltip to highlighted text in a div

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, tooltip, highlight

Inside a React 16.8 component I have a div containing text. I want to allow the user to select some of the text, highlight the selection, make a tooltip appear above the highlight, allow the user to edit the tooltip, and to persist the highlights/tooltips.

I have gotten highlighting to work via the `rangy` module but have no idea how to insert HTML into the text-containing div in a `React`-way.

Thanks for all help/guidance.

```
const Text = (props) => {
  const [highlighter, setHighlighter] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(()=>{
    rangy.init();
    let h = rangy.createHighlighter();
    h.addClassApplier(rangy.createClassApplier(classes.highlighter));
    setHighlighter(h);
  }, []);

  const select = () => {
    highlighter.highlightSelection(classes.highlighter);
    rangy.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.Text}>
      <h2>{props.text.title}</h2>
      <div className={classes.TextInner}>
        <div onMouseDown={select} onMouseUp={select}>
          {props.text.content}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

Comment: Wondering if you ever figured this out? :)

Comment: no, sorry. would still like to know....